# How to send an image via APNS in Rails?

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby, apple-push-notifications

I have built a rails app which support Apple's App as back-end to send Push Notification on Apple's Phone. Text Message and Sound File can be send successfully but now I want to send Image file as notification How can I achieve that? Any idea? Please help.

**Gems** I have used:

```
gem 'apns'
gem 'push-core'
gem 'push-apns'
```

Here is my some code:

**Configuration :**

```
Push::ConfigurationApns.create(app: 'pushtest', connections: 2, enabled: true,
    certificate: File.read('/home/gagan/ror projects/ios_push_notification/config/ck.pem'),
    feedback_poll: 60,
    sandbox: true)
```

**Message:**

```
Push::MessageApns.create(
    app: 'pushtest',
    device: 'bcc5aed28cae3dfea09cf',
    alert: 'Rails test 1 :: 20140530',
    sound: '1.aiff',
    badge: 1,
    expiry: 1.day.to_i, 
    attributes_for_device: {key: 'MSG'})
```

Thanks in Advance.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, APNS does not support images. You can only send text, sound file can be set as long a it is already in de app main bundle.

You of course send and some custom data in the push notification, which can be a link to an image. Then once the user open the push notification you can then pickup that custom data from the notification after which your app can download and display the image.

Comment: Any idea if I want to send an image then?

Comment: You can't do it directly in the push notification since it is not supported. Thus you option are to do it in your app.